# Segmentation Fault in SFML After calling sf::Window::close

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm trying to run an SFML window on a separate thread from main(). Calling sf::Window::close doesn't cause any immediate problems, however at the end of main(), possibly when the UI object is destructed, a segmentation fault error occurs. No segmentation fault occurs if sf::Window::close isn't called.

I'm running a fully updated Debian 10 install.

```
#include <thread>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(500,500), "Test");

    std::thread th(&sf::Window::close, &window);
    th.join();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. You have to deactivate the window before closing in another thread, like so. I missed this in the documentation initially.

```
#include <thread>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(500,500), "Test");

    window.setActive(false);

    std::thread th(&sf::Window::close, &window);
    th.join();
}
```